# Background image not showing. CSS. Header 1. HTML5

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a site for my class and I'm having extreme difficulties getting this header's image to show. They are in the same folder and I can get the image to show when applied directly to a specific page. I feel there is something wrong with the way my CSS is coded.

```
  h1     
     { background-color: #000033;
     background-image: <img src="sunset.jpg" "Height=72px" <alt="Sunset"> ;
     color: #FFFFFF; 
     line-height: 200% ;
     font-family: Georgia, serif; 
     text-indent: ;
     text-shadow: ;    
     margin-bottom: 0 ;}
```

so i got it to work without realizing it, here is the code i ended with.

```
    h1     
     { background-color: #000033;
     background-image: url(sunset.jpg) ;
     color: #FFFFFF; 
     line-height: 200% ;
     font-family: Georgia, serif; 
     text-indent: ;
     text-shadow: ;
     background-position: right; 
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     height: 60px; 
     padding-left: 20px;         
     margin-bottom: 0 ;}
```

Comment: I'm having difficulties applying images through CSS in general.

Comment: and my answer 30 minutes bevor your edit, didnt help?

Answer (score 2):

background image is used in css as follows

`background-image: url("sunset.jpg");`

take a look https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

When using CSS, you don’t need to use HTML tags e.g. `<img.../>` you just use the following:

```
h1     
     { background-color: #000033;
     background-image: url(“sunset.jpg");
     color: #FFFFFF; 
     line-height: 200% ;
     font-family: Georgia, serif; 
     text-indent: ;
     text-shadow: ;    
     margin-bottom: 0 ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image: url("sunset.jpg");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it's probably better to include more context/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use HTML tags inside CSS.**

Try this:

```
background-image:url ('sunset.jpg');
```

and it will work fine.